# Spark Exception : Task failed while writing rows (Spark on Kuberenetes)

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-spark-mllib, azure-aks

I have Apache Spark 2.4.1 environment on Kubernetes(Azure Kubernetes Service).

The Spark container image is made from official binary file(spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz).
It works fine on example program(e.g. PI calculation).

But I use my Scala program that use MlLib and save Word2Vec model, Spark returns an bellow error:

```
19/04/21 09:08:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 29, 10.244.0.43, executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:409)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/snappy-1.1.7-c798b2d2-1676-4e8a-bc38-a0d90c37c80d-libsnappyjava.so: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /tmp/snappy-1.1.7-c798b2d2-1676-4e8a-bc38-a0d90c37c80d-libsnappyjava.so)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:179)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadSnappyApi(SnappyLoader.java:154)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:47)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyCompressor.compress(SnappyCompressor.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.compress(CompressorStream.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.finish(CompressorStream.java:92)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.CodecFactory$HeapBytesCompressor.compress(CodecFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ColumnChunkPageWriteStore$ColumnChunkPageWriter.writePage(ColumnChunkPageWriteStore.java:95)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.writePage(ColumnWriterV1.java:147)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.flush(ColumnWriterV1.java:235)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.flush(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:122)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.flushRowGroupToStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:172)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:114)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
    ... 10 more
```

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved when the following RUN sentence was added Dockerfile which creates Spark container.

```
RUN ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message states that *libsnappyjava.so cannot find ld-linux-x86-64.so.2. This is a glibc dynamic loader. So you have two solution:

1. Use another compression lib, such gzip.
2. Edit your DockerFile Install libc6-compat in your docker image

Reference:

- [libsnappyjava-so-error-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288034/unsatisfiedlinkerror-tmp-snappy-1-1-4-libsnappyjava-so-error-loading-shared-li)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried  "2. Edit your DockerFile Install libc6-compat in your docker image", but my problem was not solved. But when I read Reference link, I got to the solution. Thank you very much!