# Kafka Mirror Maker snappy compression

Tags: apache-kafka, snappy, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to configure a mirror maker between two kafkas and the data mirroring works fine for topics without compression. When mirroring a topic with a snappy compression I get the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/snappy-1.1.10-00c148a7-468e-478a-855c-cabd60c7f21d-libsnappyjava.so (Read-only file system)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.extractLibraryFile(SnappyLoader.java:242)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.findNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:358)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:179)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadSnappyApi(SnappyLoader.java:157)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.init(Snappy.java:70)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:47)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.hasNextChunk(SnappyInputStream.java:446)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.read(SnappyInputStream.java:477)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:270)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ByteUtils.readUnsignedVarint(ByteUtils.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ByteUtils.readVarint(ByteUtils.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecord.readFrom(DefaultRecord.java:296)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$2.doReadRecord(DefaultRecordBatch.java:278)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$StreamRecordIterator.readNext(DefaultRecordBatch.java:617)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:582)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.nextFetchedRecord(Fetcher.java:1556)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1591)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1432)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:635)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1303)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$ConsumerWrapper.receive(MirrorMaker.scala:325)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread.run(MirrorMaker.scala:214)
[2023-11-09 20:30:08,767] ERROR [mirrormaker-thread-1] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no snappyjava in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2678)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1886)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:185)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadSnappyApi(SnappyLoader.java:157)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.init(Snappy.java:70)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:47)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.hasNextChunk(SnappyInputStream.java:446)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.read(SnappyInputStream.java:477)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:270)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ByteUtils.readUnsignedVarint(ByteUtils.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ByteUtils.readVarint(ByteUtils.java:205)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecord.readFrom(DefaultRecord.java:296)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$2.doReadRecord(DefaultRecordBatch.java:278)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$StreamRecordIterator.readNext(DefaultRecordBatch.java:617)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:582)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:551)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.nextFetchedRecord(Fetcher.java:1556)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1591)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1432)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:684)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:635)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1303)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
        at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$ConsumerWrapper.receive(MirrorMaker.scala:325)
        at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread.run(MirrorMaker.scala:214)
[2023-11-09 20:30:08,767] ERROR [mirrormaker-thread-2] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.hasNextChunk(SnappyInputStream.java:446)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.read(SnappyInputStream.java:477)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:270)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ByteUtils.readUnsignedVarint(ByteUtils.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ByteUtils.readVarint(ByteUtils.java:205)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecord.readFrom(DefaultRecord.java:296)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$2.doReadRecord(DefaultRecordBatch.java:278)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$StreamRecordIterator.readNext(DefaultRecordBatch.java:617)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:582)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:551)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.nextFetchedRecord(Fetcher.java:1556)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1591)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1432)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:684)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:635)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1303)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
        at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$ConsumerWrapper.receive(MirrorMaker.scala:325)
        at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread.run(MirrorMaker.scala:214)
```

Docker image: `confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.15` AND `confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.1`
Tried copying the jar file: `COPY snappy-java-1.1.10.5.jar /lib/snappy-java-1.1.10.5.jar` did not help.
Following the discussion below did not help as well

> [UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/snappy-1.1.4-libsnappyjava.so Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288034/unsatisfiedlinkerror-tmp-snappy-1-1-4-libsnappyjava-so-error-loading-shared-li/55568352#55568352)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the mirror maker does not come with Snappy Lib included. What I did was to copy `libsnappyjava.so` into `/usr/lib/` of the docker image and it worked. I've taken the `.so` file from the github repo [here](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/xerial/snappy/native/Linux/x86_64/libsnappyjava.so)

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.15

COPY libsnappyjava.so /usr/lib/libsnappyjava.so

USER root
RUN chmod 755 /usr/lib/libsnappyjava.so

USER appuser
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be because snappy wants to write in /tmp and it is mounted as read-only.

I can not test it right now, but I would say you can pass JVM_OPTS using KAFKA_OPTS environment variable.

Example:

```
KAFKA_OPTS=-Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/path/to/newtmp
```